# What is the best way to install NodeJS modules without NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, module

I don't have SSH access, but i can restart server via pm2 and i have access to ftp. How can i install modules to my server?

Is moving node_modules folder works? I didn't try but i want to make sure. And my server is linux and my pc is windows.

Comment: moving `node_modules` and `package.json` should works. one exception is when the package is native addon. then moving from those folders from windows to linux can be a problem